# quadratic eq proof ;a,b,c odd, roots can't be rational no.

Tags: proof-explanation, quadratics

Given odd integers $a,b,c$ prove that the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ cannot have a solution x which is a rational number

My approach:
if $a =1$ , $b=3$ , $c=1$;
then the eq. $x^2 + 3x + c = 0$ has roots

$x_1=-0.381...$,

$x_2=-2.62...$ ;

which is indeed true
but how can we prove this result??
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a,b,c$ are odd integers, and suppose the equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
has a rational root, $r={\large{\frac{p}{q}}}$ say, where $p,q$ are integers, and $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$ (i.e., the fraction is reduced to lowest terms).
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&ar^2 + br + c = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\left({\small{\frac{p}{q}}}\right)^2+b\left({\small{\frac{p}{q}}}\right) + c = 0\\[4pt]\implies\;&ap^2 + bpq + cq^2 = 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Consider $3$ cases . . .

Case $(1)\,$:$\;p,q$ are both even.

Then $\text{gcd}(p,q) > 1$, contradiction.

Case $(2)\,$:$\;p,q$ are both odd.

Then the LHS of the equation $ap^2 + bpq + cq^2 = 0$ is odd (since all three terms are odd), contradiction, since the RHS is even.

Case $(3)\,$:$\;$One of $p,q$ is even, and the other is odd.

Then the LHS of the equation $ap^2 + bpq + cq^2=0$ is odd (since  two of the terms are even, and the remaining term is odd), contradiction, since the RHS is even.

Thus, all $3$ cases yield a contradiction.

It follows that the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ does not have a rational root.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is integer and the roots are rational then both roots have an odd numerator (since their product is $c/a$). Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

We need $$b^2-4ca$$ for the perfect square $=d^2$(say)

If $b$ is odd, so will be $d$

$$\implies4ca=b^2-d^2$$

Now if $x$ is odd, $$x^2\equiv1\pmod8\implies8|(b^2-d^2)$$ but $8\nmid4ca$